# How can I put an if in html so that the value of 'object.star' is equal to 1 and 2 at the same time

Tags: python, html, django-templates

I tried this methods (with 'and, or' between two values)but 'and' only applies the first value('four')
Only in this way could I solve the problem by setting two separate 'ifs' for both, that this is not the right way

This is my code:

```
                {% for object in object_list %}
                    **{% if object.star == "four" or "five" %}**
                    <div class="col mb-5">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <!-- Product image-->
                            <img class="card-img-top">{{object.thumbnail_tag}}
                            <!-- Product details-->
                            <div class="card-body p-4">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <!-- Product name-->
                                    <a href="{% url 'detail' object.slug %}"><h5 class="fw-bolder">{{object.name}}</h5></a>
                                    <!-- Product reviews-->
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center small text-warning mb-2">
                                    {% if object.star == "four" %}
                                        <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                        <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                        <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                        <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                    {% elif object.star == "five" %}
                                        <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                        <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                        <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                        <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                        <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Product price-->
                                    {% if object.newprice == none %}
                                    {{object.currency}}{{object.price}}
                                    {% else %}
                                    <span class="text-muted text-decoration-line-through">{{object.currency}}{{object.price}}</span>
                                    <span style="color: #ffc107;">{{object.newprice}}</span>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Product actions-->
                            <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
                                <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto" href="#">Add to cart</a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please look at your post and ask yourself if this is the best version in which you could present your problem. Thanks

Comment: They do not even see that I'm a New contributor

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Who is "they"?

Comment: @Neuron my first comment has been deleted.I said yes this is the best version and SO is very helpful but some people  give me negative score and it will effect on my account,(They do not even see that I'm a New contributor)

Comment: @Saleh, I think what Neuron meant was that we should try to simplify our questions as much as we can- this can often help us get to the answer ourselves. In this case maybe your question could have been narrowed down to 'How do I write a logical IF OR statement in a Django template?' with a simple code example of what you have tried.
For more info you can take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @P.Moloney, yes I agree. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object.star == 'four' or 'five'` doesn't do what you think.

It will first consider `object.star == 'four'` which is either `True` or `False`. If `False` it will then consider `five` (which is truthy).

You need to explicitly do 2 tests:

```
object.star == 'four' or 'object.star == 'five'
```